# Does London Luton Airport have any bookstore with a good selection of travel guidebooks?

Tags: shopping, guidebooks, ltn

I have a couple of hours layover at LTN (not enough to go shopping in the city) and would like to pick up the latest edition (yes, traditional paper version) for my destination.

Does London Luton Airport have any bookstore with a good selection of travel guidebooks?

This is a very slightly altered copy-and-paste of Jonik's similar question [Is there a bookstore at Heathrow with a good selection of LP or Moon guides?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61608/is-there-a-bookstore-at-heathrow-with-a-good-selection-of-lp-or-moon-guides/61622#61622)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [WH Smith](http://www.london-luton.co.uk/shopping/holiday-essentials/whsmith-1), [both sides of security](http://www.london-luton.co.uk/shopping/holiday-essentials/whsmith-en) at Luton airport. They might have guidebooks there. You might want to call and ask in advance. With enough luck you might even be able to pre-order them.